# Passing values through javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating small shopping-cart program, I'm using following code to input values.

```
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart : <?php echo $row['PART_NO']; ?>" onclick="addtocart('<?php echo $item; ?>')" />
```

value goes through following javascript code.

```
function addtocart(pid){
    alert(pid);
    document.form1.productid.value=pid;
    document.form1.command.value='add';
    document.form1.submit();
}

<body>
<form name="form1">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>

<?php
if ( isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' &&    $_REQUEST['productid']>0 ){
    $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1);
    header("location:shoppingcart.php");
    exit();
}

?>
```

when I'm inserting `productid` like **`02190249`** it goes through javascript code and php code and loading the shoppingcart.php. but inserting `productid` like **`PF161202`** its not loading the `shoppingcart.php`. how can I pass values like **`PF161202`** to php code through js.

Comment: You are printing the body before you want to send a header. You need to send the header before you print anything. Put the PHP code above the HTML and JS code.

Comment: Have you tried the special value `alert("I'm in your codez rekking your s***?")`? I hear it gives some special results...

Comment: yes . special values working in alert, tried that.

Comment: It's beause you checked `$_REQUEST['productid']>0` which is working fine with `numbers` but not for `string`. you have to remove this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$_REQUEST['productid']>0` from your php code. It is checking only for `numbers`(02190249) which is greater then `0` but as per your question you are passing a `string`(PF161202).

```
<?php
if ( isset($_REQUEST['command']) && $_REQUEST['command'] == 'add' && ($_REQUEST['productid'] != '')){
    $pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1);
    header("location:shoppingcart.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: the code works. but unable to print it using following code, $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
     $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
     $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
     $pname=get_product_name($pid);
     if($q==0) continue;